# Injectivity for bimodules and Hochschild cohomology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra and let $X$ be an $A$-bimodule. Is there a notion of (relative) injectivity for $X$ which would imply that $\mathcal{H}^n(A,X)$ vanishes for all $n\ge 1$? Here $\mathcal{H}^n(A,X)$ denotes the continuous Hochschild cohomology of $A$ with coefficients in $X$ ($X$ can be assumed to be dual $A$-bimodule).

I expected there is such a notion, but after reading books by Helemskii, Runde and a few other sources on cohomology of Banach algebras I can't seem to find a general statement of this type, even though versions of projectivity and injectivity are discussed there.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something. Doesn't relative $A$-bi-injectivity of $X$ (a.k.a. relative injectivity as an $A^e$-module) do the job? And if $X$ is a dual module then this is the same as asking for its predual to be (relatively) A-biflat? (This just comes out of Helemskii's version of Ext for Banach modules.)

Comment: @Yemon: why not write that up into an answer??

Comment: @Yemon: what do you mean by $A^{\epsilon}$? Is it the unitization of $A$? 

Comment: @Matt: Because I seem to remember Piotr has written a paper using (or referring to) this kind of stuff, and it is all in Helemskii's pink book (HBTA). @Piotr: $A^e$ is the enveloping algebra of A, this is A proj. tensor A equipped with product $(a\otimes b)(c\otimes d) = (ac\otimes db)$, and its main feature is that every $A$-bimodule can be regarded as a left $A^e$-bimodule, and conversely.

Comment: @Yemon: Thanks! So, to summarize I take an $A$-bimodule $X$ and view it as a left $A^{\epsilon}$-module. Then if this left $A$-module is injective as a left module then $\mathcal{H}^n(A,X)=0$? If so, this answers the question.

In that paper you are referring to the point of view was essentially that of bounded cohomology of groups and the translation to Banach algebras is not straightforward at all. At least that is the motivation for my question. 

Comment: @Piotr: That is correct (I am assuming that A is unital, which if you are working with algebras arising from discrete groups, is usually the case). In practice, what one needs to show is that the natural embedding from $J: X \to {\mathcal L}(A\hat\otimes A, X)$, defined by $J(x)(a\otimes b) = axb$, has a (continuous, linear) left inverse which is an $A$-bimodule map -- this is equivalent to being A-bi-injective, at least in the unital case.

Comment: @Yemon: you should definitely post it as an answer.

Comment: I'd heard about (regular?) Hochschild cohomology but not continuous Hochschild cohomology, what's the difference? Anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of people have encouraged me to post this as an answer, so here goes. I am currently without a copy of Helemskii's Pink Book so I can't give chapter-and-verse references as I would have liked. Everything that follows should be somewhere in there, although perhaps expressed slightly differently, and probably slightly better. Certainly what follows is too wordy, but I haven't had time to work out a condensed version.

To recap: Piotr is asking about the continuous Hochschild cohomology groups ${\mathcal H}^n(A,X)$ where $A$ is a Banach algebra and $X$ a Banach $A$-bimodule. To simplify the discussion slightly, I shall assume that $A$ has an identity element (which is indeed the case if $A$ is one of the usual convolution-type algebras associated to a discrete group) and that $X$ is unit-linked, i.e. that the identity of $A$ acts as the identity operator on $X$.

### Conceptual/abstract POV (Helemskian)

As in the classical theory of Cartan-Eilenberg vintage, (continuous) Hochschild cohomology can be expressed in terms of relative Ext. One way to approach this, as Helemskii does, is to introduce the enveloping algebra $A^e$ of a unital Banach algebra $A$.
This has underlying Banach space $A\hat{\otimes} A$ (projective tensor product) and has multiplication defined by $(a\otimes b)\cdot (c\otimes d) = (ab\otimes dc)$.

(The definition is slightly different for the non-unital case, and the artificial dichotomy that arises in places in the Pink Book is something that vexes some of us. But I digress...)

The purpose of doing this is as follows: every Banach $A$-bimodule $X$ becomes a left Banach $A^e$-module via $(a\otimes b)\cdot x = axb$; and conversely, every left Banach $A^e$-module becomes a Banach $A$-bimodule via the same formula. Now, taking as read the definition of relative Ext that is given in the Pink Book, we have
$$ {\mathcal H}^n(A,X) \cong \operatorname{Ext}_{A^e}^n (A,X) $$
This is an isomorphism of seminormed spaces for each $n$ (I guess it would be more precise to say an isomorphism of seminormed-space-valued $\delta$-functors or some such high-falutin' phrase)

Now, recall that if $B$ is a Banach algebra, then a left Banach $B$-module $X$ is said to be (relatively) $B$-injective if it satisfies the following:

whenever $N$ is a left Banach $B$-module and $M$ is a closed $B$-submodule of $N$ which is complemented as a Banach subspace, then each continuous linear $B$-module map $M\to X$ has a continuous linear extension to a $B$-module map $N\to X$.

Moreover, if $X$ is relatively $B$-injective then $\operatorname{Ext}_B^n(\cdot,X)=0$ for each $n\geq 1$. (The converse also holds, in fact.) Therefore:

> if $X$ is relatively $A^e$-injective, then ${\mathcal H}^n(A,X)=0$ for all $n\geq 1$.

### The get-your-hands-dirty approach (Johnsonite)

We continue to suppose that $A$ has an identity element. Now let $E$ be any Banach space and equip $V_E :={\mathcal L}(A\hat\otimes A, E)$ with the following natural $A$-bimodule structure:
$$ (b\cdot T \cdot a)(c\otimes d) = T(ac\otimes db) \quad\quad(T\in V_E). $$

**Claim:** ${\mathcal H}^n(A,V_E)=0$ for all $n\geq 1$.

This is most easily proved by proving something stronger:

**Exercise:** Let $\delta: {\mathcal C}^n(A,V_E)\to {\mathcal C}^{n+1}(A,V_E)$ denote the Hochschild coboundary operator. Define $\sigma: {\mathcal C}^{n+1}(A,V_E) \to {\mathcal C}^n(A,V_E)$ by
$$ [\sigma\psi(a_1,\dots,a_n)]{(c\otimes d)} = [\psi(d,a_1,\dots, a_n)]{(c\otimes 1)}. $$
Then $\delta\sigma(\psi)+\sigma\delta(\psi) =\psi$ for every $\psi\in\mathcal C^k(A,V_E)$.

We now observe the following: if $V$ is any Banach $A$-bimodule, and it can be written as $V\cong X\oplus Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are closed $A$-sub-bimodules of $V$, then
$$ {\mathcal H}^n(A,V) \cong {\mathcal H}^n(A,X) \oplus {\mathcal H}^n(A,Y) \quad\hbox{for all $n$.} $$
One can check this directly or appeal to the long exact sequence of Hochschild cohomology (which is a special case of the one for relative Ext).

Finally, for each Banach $A$-bimodule $X$ there is a canonical $A$-bimodule map $J:X\to V_X$ which is defined by $[J(x)](c\otimes d) = dxc$. Therefore:

> If there exists an $A$-bimodule map $P:V_X\to X$ such that $PJ$ is the identity, then ${\mathcal H}^n(A, X)=0$ for all $n\geq 1$.

### Clowns to the left of me, jokers to the right

As may be apparent to anyone who's read this far: the two conditions we have obtained on $X$, each of which implies that Hochschild cohomology with coefficients in $X$ vanishes, are one and the same condition. [The calculations in the second version actually show that $V_E$ is $A$-bi-injective - meaning the same as $A^e$-injective. This relied on $A$ having an identity element!  Then, knowing that a complemented submodule of an injective module is injective, we see that the second condition implies $X$ is $A$-bi-injective.] The nice thing about the direct approach is that it gives one explicit formulas one can try even in settings where the coefficient module is not bi-injective (see for instance [my first excuse for a paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.FA/0606364) ). Personally I think it is good to have both points of view.

It should lastly be noted that almost none of the above actually used analysis - everything is taken care of by working in a particular category with a particular tensor product. So what I have just written out is no more than was known at the time of Cartan-Eilenberg.

Comment: Having typed all that out, I guess I should really have written a blog post and left a link here. Ah well.

Comment: This is great, thanks for such a complete answer!